# How to convert from string to char[] and then to long[]

Tags: c#

Ok so my goal is to convert from string "1234567" to char array what I managed to achive(incredible) but now I am stuck and have no idea what I did wrong here...

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Digitize(1234567));
    }
    public static long[] Digitize(long n)
    {
        string l = n.ToString();
        char[] p = l.ToCharArray();
        long[] nums = new long[p.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < p.Length; i++)
        {
            nums[i] = long.Parse(p[i].ToString());
        }
        
        return nums;
    }
```

All I have in output is "System.Int64[]"
(I would love to see some linq answers if that is possible)

Comment: Why not return `p`? What do you need the `long[]` for?

Comment: You might see values `long[]` instead of tostring

Comment: @Xerillio  just practicing to be able to do it if I'll ever have to

Comment: *I would love to see some linq answers* - not wishing to be disparaging, but my concern with asking for LINQ stuff would be that it would only add to confusion.

Comment: You don't need the char array bit; you can index a string to receive a char in exactly the same way you index a char array. Ideally you wouldn't use char for any of this; it can be done mathematically with divide and modulo

Comment: `1234567.ToString().Select(c => long.Parse(c.ToString()))` should do the trick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you did everything correctly.

Problem is your output.

Try:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    long[]? result = Digitize(1234567);
    foreach (long number in result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(number);
    }
}
```